# how to pass object as a parameter to the function

Tags: javascript, object

```
var car = {make: "Honda", model:"Civic", color:"Silver"};

    for(var prop in car)

        console.log(prop);
```

i got the output of all the properties of the car i.e :"
make,
model,
color"

```
var car = {make: "Honda", model:"Civic", color:"Silver"};

var GetObjectPropertyNames = function(obj) {

    if(obj===null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    for(var prop in obj)
    {
        return prop;
    }


}
console.log(GetObjectPropertyNames(car));
```

when i executed this code. i got only one property of the car. i.e only "make" as an output. 
may i know where i went wrong? and what is the difference b/w those two snippets?

Comment: *"and what is the difference b/w those two snippets?"* - Well, the code inside the loop is quite different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `Object.keys()` to obtain an array of the property names.  You don't need to write a function to do this yourself.

```
var car = {make: "Honda", model:"Civic", color:"Silver"};

var props = Object.keys(car);    // ["make", "model", "color"]
```

---

FYI, your function was only returning a single property name because you use `return` on the first property you find with `return prop` and a function is done executing as soon as you return.

If you wanted to write this yourself, you could put all the properties into an array and then return the array when done (though `Object.keys()` already does this for you).

Comment: @Arun - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you `return` immediately after finding the first property name. A function can only return once.

Maybe push the property names into an array in the loop and return that.